# how to associate Site Content type with Reusable workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-foundation

I have created Reusable Workflow through Sharepoint designer (Sharepoint foundation 2013) and associated with site content type.

Now, I have saved this as a template(eg: TestWf.wsp). I have to deploy this in production(Sharepoint Foundation 2013) environment, for this I manually created same Site Content Type in production environment and import wsp file.

Here I can able to see that the Workflow in imported successfully but it was not associated the Content type and when I am trying to associate with it Content type(option available in Ribbon in sharepoint designer 2013 foundation) it was not visible.

Please suggest where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing anything wrong. From MSDN: *"Unlike previous versions, SharePoint 2013 does not support workflows that are scoped to a content type (SPContentType). [...]"*

However, after moving your reusable content type to a different site, you can associate it with a list using this PowerShell script:

```
$wfm = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($Web)
$defSevice = $wfm.GetWorkflowDeploymentService()
$wfDefs = $defSevice.EnumerateDefinitions($false)
$wfDef = $wfDefs | where {$_.DisplayName -eq $WorkflowName}

$wfDef.RestrictToType = "List"
$wfDef.RestrictToScope = $ApprovalListId
$defSevice.SaveDefinition($wfDef);

$wfsubService = $wfm.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()


$sub = New-object Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowSubscription
$sub.DefinitionId = $wfDef.Id
$sub.Enabled = $true
$sub.Name = $wfDef.DisplayName

$startOptions = New-Object "System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.String]"
$startOptions.Add("WorkflowStart")
$sub.EventTypes = $startOptions

$sub.SetProperty("HistoryListId", $HistoryListId)
$sub.SetProperty("TaskListId", $TaskListId)

$wfSubService.PublishSubscriptionForList($sub, $ApprovalListId);
```

Make sure your content type (with all the columns) is on the list already.

Comment: SharePoint 2013 Workflow platform is not installed on my environment i.e Sharepoint Foundation 2013. Will this script run? Also I am using Document Library instead of List.

Comment: I am using Sharepoint 2010 Workflow platform.

Comment: Library is a List, in a way :) So basically - same thing. If you're using 2010 Workflows, the script is not applicable in that case. In your case, follow this - https://chanakyajayabalan.wordpress.com/2012/01/02/copyingmoving-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflows/ or this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/allengeorge/2013/04/17/move-copy-a-designer-reusable-workflow-to-a-new-site-farm/